# Call Client Side Event And Server Side Event Of Text Box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a java script function

```
function here()
{
    if ( confirm('You Want to Change date And Data Both') ) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

I am Calling This Function `onChange` Event Of Text Box..

When it returns true my server side function should be called...
if it returns false it does not be called ..

Which I have written in

```
ontextchanged="Txt_Date_Curent_TextChanged"
```

But in both cases my server side function is not called....

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You cannot call a server side function just like that from client side. You need to learn AJAX to do something like that.

Comment: You know you can simplify that function down to a one-liner: `return confirm('...');`

Comment: i know that but i write this for testing ...

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoPostBack=True`.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return here()">
  <asp:TextBox 
           ID="TextBox1" 
           AutoPostBack="true"  
           OnTextChanged="Txt_Date_Curent_TextChanged" 
           runat="server">
  </asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Onchange="return here()" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>                                              protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("KILL UUUU");

    }

Comment: Attach here() function at onreturn attribute of form tag.